# how to change desktop background in ubuntu desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, ssh

I was using gnome desktop environment at the start but i switched to unity environment by install unity shell via this command

```
sudo apt get install Ubuntu-desktop
```

after this I have many issues like I cant change my desktop background while using unity environment and I cannot lock the screen while using GNOME desktop

can any one help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: try 

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true

Comment: @Geo i didn't get you can you elaborate your explain please

Comment: open a terminal and type the following command:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true`